# Problem with Google Calendar API "getTimes()" method

Tags: java, api, gwt, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get several informations from google calendar's API in JAVA. While trying to access to informations about the time of an event I got a problem. I do the following:

```
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("project_name");
myService.setUserCredentials("user", "pwd");
URL feedUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");
CalendarQuery q = new CalendarQuery(feedUrl);
CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = myService.query(q, CalendarEventFeed.class);
for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
              CalendarEventEntry g = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
List<When> t = g.getTimes();
//other operations
}
```

The list t obtained with getTimes() on a CalendarEventEntry is **always empty** and I can't figure out why. This seems strange to me since for a calendar event it should always exist a description of when it should happen... what am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware or single time events vs recurring events:

`getTimes` is used for single time events.

For recurring events you have to use `getRecurrence()`

Or, you can set the `singleevents` property to true, so recurring events are returned as single events and getTimes will return a non-empty list:

```
CalendarQuery q = new CalendarQuery(feedUrl);
q.setStringCustomParameter("singleevents", "true");
CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = myService.query(q, CalendarEventFeed.class);
// process the results as single-events now...
```

Reference: look for the text "singleevents" [here](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html).

Note: if you use a magic-cookie url to access the feed, then recurring events are always returned as recurring events, no matter how you set the `singleevents` property in the query.

Answer (score 0):

[This Google support request is also relevant.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=3472d683f69a8d21&hl=en) (The same answer Toto provided but with additional information)